# How the find the records which are not duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table which will have possible duplicate records.

```
 id: 24,
  name: "vamsi",
  mobile: "7639817688",
  company: "digi",
  requirement: "mobile app",
  created_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:33 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:33 UTC +00:00,
  email_sent: false>,
 #<Contact:0x00000006d7a4f0
  id: 25,
  name: "vamsi",
  mobile: "7639817688",
  company: "digi",
  requirement: "mobile app",
  created_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:57 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:57 UTC +00:00,
  email_sent: false>]
```

Now I would like to find the unique records on which email_sent is false. I have tried this 
`Contact.where(email_sent: false).distinct`

```
Contact Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."email_sent" = $1  [["email_sent", false]]
=> [#<Contact:0x00000006a1a698
  id: 25,
  name: "vamsi",
  mobile: "7639817688",
  company: "digi",
  requirement: "mobile app",
  created_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:57 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:57 UTC +00:00,
  email_sent: false>,
 #<Contact:0x00000006a1a418
  id: 24,
  name: "vamsi",
  mobile: "7639817688",
  company: "digi",
  requirement: "mobile app",
  created_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:33 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:05:33 UTC +00:00,
  email_sent: false>]
```

But I would not want 2 records, since both are same. I would like only one to be shown. Is there any way I can solve this.

Comment: You have to select fields which are different before attaching distinct to it. Like: `.select(:name, :mobile, :company, :requirement, :email_sent).distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Try group by email_sent after using where:

```
Contact.where(email_sent: false).group(:email_sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

First part, the model should have validations so that these kinds of data won't be stored

It can be done via this

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:mobile, :requirement, :company]`

Second part, still if you want to query something like above scenario. You have to do this

`Contact.select(:name, :company, :mobile, :requirement).where(email_sent: false).distinct` would be the query

ps: Answer picked up from all the comments in the question